GitHub Apps Installation
I am using GitHub Apps in order to integrate GitHub in our product.
Looks like I need to have the app installed (not only request a token) in order to list user's private repos.
So what I am doing is opening a pop up with the installation of the app, using this link https://github.com/apps/APP-NAME/installations/new
This works fine for the first time, the app gets installed and I receive the code to exchange for the token.
The problem is when the user already has the app installed, I would expect this new installation dialog to skip the installation setup(since the user already did that) and instead give me the access token and close the pop up.
Do I have any way to achieve that? Maybe specifying some kind of parameter?
If not, can I use git hub apps in some way that allows me to retrieve the private repos without having to install it (AFAIK the legacy Oath apps allow you to do that by specifying scopes)?

Once you install GitHub App into a user’s account, you need to obtain installation ID. This ID does not change.
In order to get private repos in the account you need to send GutHub API request with an installation access token. To obtain it you need to perform two steps

Sign GitHub App JWT with the private key of the app - see here
Exchange JWT for an installation access token - see here

Here is a sample workflow to do this:
name: Get GitHub App Installation Access Token and List Repositories

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  get-installation-token:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Generate GitHub App JWT
    id: generate_jwt
    uses: tibdex/github-app-token@v1
    with:
      app_id: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_APP_ID }}
      private_key: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY }}

  - name: Get GitHub App Installation Access Token
    id: get_installation_token
    uses: actions/github-script@v6
    with:
      script: |
        const jwt = `{{ steps.generate_jwt.outputs.token }}`;
        const octokit = new github.getOctokit(jwt);
        const { data: installations } = await octokit.request('GET /app/installations');
        const installation_id = installations[0].id;
        const { data: tokenData } = await octokit.request('POST /app/installations/{installation_id}/access_tokens', {
          installation_id
        });
        return tokenData.token;

  - name: List Repositories Accessible by GitHub App
    uses: actions/github-script@v6
    with:
      script: |
        const token = `{{ steps.get_installation_token.outputs.result }}`;
        const octokit = new github.getOctokit(token);
        const { data: repos } = await octokit.request('GET /users/{user-name}/repos');
        console.log('Repositories accessible by the GitHub App installation:', repos);

  - name: Display Repositories
    run: |
      echo "Repositories: ${{ steps.list_repos.outputs.repos }}"


Thank you for your answer, but it's not really related to what I asked. What I wanted to know is if it's possible somehow to get private repos without installing the app (only by authorizing it, like oauth apps work). Or if not, at least skip the installation part when the user already has the app installed.
